# What is the story with Thankful for Today and the transfer of dev control?

Tags: history

Legend has it, Monero once had another developer, but he displeased the community and was replaced.

How did this transfer control happen? What is the story? (And when does it gets its own manga?)

Answer (score 4):

thankful_for_today launched it as bitMonero and the other devs voted to drop the bit part and Monero was born.